# python: most elegant way to intersperse a list with an element

Tags: python, list

Input:

```
intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"])
```

Output:

```
["once", 666, "upon", 666, "a", 666, 90, 666, None, 666, "time"]
```

What's the most elegant (read: Pythonic) way to write `intersperse`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would have written a generator myself, but like this:

```
def joinit(iterable, delimiter):
    it = iter(iterable)
    yield next(it)
    for x in it:
        yield delimiter
        yield x
```

Comment: note: the first arg could be called `iterable`. And the function could be called just `joinit()`. btw, the nice thing about your solution that it also works for an empty sequence (`next()` raises `StopIteration` and the generator `joinseq()` returns immediately).

Comment: @J.F.: Thanks for the tip.  Naming it `iterable` would have been the first thing I did.  But instead, I got into the habit of calling it `sequence` as everyone else has.  :)

Comment: I like the pun of `joinit` meaning both "join it" and "join it[erable]"

Comment: @claudiu I like that you came back two years later to point that out :)

Answer (score 21):

[**`itertools`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to the rescue
- or -
*How many itertools functions can you use in one line?*

```
from itertools import chain, izip, repeat, islice

def intersperse(delimiter, seq):
    return islice(chain.from_iterable(izip(repeat(delimiter), seq)), 1, None)
```

Usage:

```
>>> list(intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"])
["once", 666, "upon", 666, "a", 666, 90, 666, None, 666, "time"]
```

Comment: Ah back to the last version.  :)

Comment: @JeffMercado: Yes, thanks for your comment ( I think it was you?) :) It works indeed...

Comment: @JeffMercado: I know.... synchronisation problem ;) Not sure if this is really efficient though... so many iterators.... I like your solution :) But it is nice to know more than one way (despite Pythons motto that there is only one ;))

Comment: Note that the expansion of the arguments for `chain` requires iterating over all of `s`.  This is a big problem for something like `intersperse(666, repeat(777))`, which the generator answers handle fine.  You should be able to fix this by using `chain.from_iterable(izip(...))` instead.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh I didn't know. But makes sense now that I think about it... Thank you, will put this in my answer.

Comment: This would be elegant if Python's syntax were different, I think

Answer (score 18):

Another option that works for sequences:

```
def intersperse(seq, value):
    res = [value] * (2 * len(seq) - 1)
    res[::2] = seq
    return res
```

Answer (score 8):

Solution is trivial using [**`more_itertools.intersperse`**](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.intersperse):

```
>>> from more_itertools import intersperse
>>> list(intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"]))
['once', 666, 'upon', 666, 'a', 666, 90, 666, None, 666, 'time']
```

Technically, this answer isn't "writing" `intersperse`, it's just using it from another library. But it might save others from having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a simple generator.

```
def intersperse(val, sequence):
    first = True
    for item in sequence:
        if not first:
            yield val
        yield item
        first = False
```

and then you can get your list like so:

```
>>> list(intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"]))
['once', 666, 'upon', 666, 'a', 666, 90, 666, None, 666, 'time']
```

alternatively you could do:

```
def intersperse(val, sequence):
    for i, item in enumerate(sequence):
        if i != 0:
            yield val
        yield item
```

I'm not sure which is more pythonic

Comment: i like this the best so far: no slicing, no doing anything specific to the iterator like calling `len`.. it aint a 1 liner but it looks nicer than the 1 liners

Answer (score 4):

```
def intersperse(word,your_list):
    x = [j for i in your_list for j in [i,word]]

>>> intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"])
['once', 666, 'upon', 666, 'a', 666, 90, 666, None, 666, 'time', 666]
```

**[Edit]** Corrected code below:

```
def intersperse(word,your_list):
    x = [j for i in your_list for j in [i,word]]
    x.pop()
    return x

>>> intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"])
['once', 666, 'upon', 666, 'a', 666, 90, 666, None, 666, 'time']
```

Comment: the last `666` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
from itertools import chain,izip_longest

def intersperse(x,y):
     return list(chain(*izip_longest(x,[],fillvalue=y)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with this now, googled to see if there was something better... and IMHO there wasn't :-)

```
def intersperse(e, l):    
    return list(itertools.chain(*[(i, e) for i in l]))[0:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if it's pythonic, but it's pretty simple:

```
def intersperse(elem, list):
    result = []
    for e in list:
      result.extend([e, elem])
    return result[:-1]
```

Comment: i thought of that, but i don't like that you slice the list at the end

Comment: I could go with initialising result to list[0], but then I'd have to first check if list is empty.  [][:-1] conveniently returns [] sparing me from that problem.  Seems like the generator answer is the only one so far that doesn't employ slicing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this one looks pretty nice and easy to grasp compared to the `yield next(iterator)` or `itertools.iterator_magic()` one :)

```
def list_join_seq(seq, sep):
  for i, elem in enumerate(seq):
    if i > 0: yield sep
    yield elem

print(list(list_join_seq([1, 2, 3], 0)))  # [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic and easy you could do is:

```
a = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']

# my separator is : || separator ||
# hack is extra thing : --

'--|| separator ||--'.join(a).split('--')
```

output:

```
['abc','|| separator ||','def','|| separator ||','ghi','|| separator ||','jkl']
```

Comment: I like this one liner for small lists, but I'd suggest using a more unique delimiter.  '--' seems like a common enough string that it'll bite someone down the line.  Use something like '$)($' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems general and efficient:

```
def intersperse(lst, fill=...):
    """
    >>> list(intersperse([1,2,3,4]))
    [1, Ellipsis, 2, Ellipsis, 3, Ellipsis, 4]
    """
    return chain(*zip(lst[:-1], repeat(fill)), [lst[-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's list comprehension:

```py
def intersperse(iterable, element):
    return [iterable[i // 2] if i % 2 == 0 else element for i in range(2 * len(iterable) - 1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
>>> def intersperse(e, l):
...    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, zip(l, [e]*len(l)))
>>> intersperse(666, ["once", "upon", "a", 90, None, "time"])
('once', 666, 'upon', 666, 'a', 666, 90, 666, None, 666, 'time', 666)
```

If you don't want a trailing `666`, then `return reduce(...)[:-1]`.

Comment: Minor improvement: using 'operator.concat' instead of the lambda.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one that's readable, and doesn't use itertools, just good-ol' list comprehension:

```py
def intersperse(delim, items):
    items = [[delim, item] for item in items]
    return [i for is in items[1:] for i in is]
```

it's also trivially extendable to prefixing every item, as can be useful when you take a list of values and want to turn them into CLI arguments. Just remove the `[1:]` part. You can also trivially make it suffix rather than prefix by swapping `delim` and `item` in the first line.

Answer (score -2):

```
def intersperse(items, delim):
    i = iter(items)
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + [delim, y], i, [i.next()])
```

Should work for lists or generators.

Comment: That's pretty inefficient though, you call a function for each element and do list addition instead of append/extend

Comment: This is O(n²); an O(n) solution is trivially possible and also simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't notice the question was "fastest way to intersperse a list with an element?".