# Add an item between each item already in the list

Tags: python, list, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: most elegant way to intersperse a list with an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655708/python-most-elegant-way-to-intersperse-a-list-with-an-element)

Assuming I have the following list:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

How can I append a new item (in this case a `-`) between each item in this list, so that my list will look like the following?

```
['a','-','b','-','c','-','d','-','e']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 54):

Here's a solution that I would expect to be very fast -- I believe all these operations will happen at optimized c speed.

```
def intersperse(lst, item):
    result = [item] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)
    result[0::2] = lst
    return result
```

Tested:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> intersperse(l, '-')
[1, '-', 2, '-', 3, '-', 4, '-', 5]
```

The line that does all the work, `result[0::2] = lst`, uses [extended slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) and slice assignment. The third `step` parameter tells python to assign values from `lst` to every second position in `l`.

Comment: This could be a cleaner way for the first assignment: `result = [None, item] * len(lst)`

Comment: @pabouk, yes that could work, though you'd have to call `pop` at the end (to get red of the extra `item`). I'll test it when I get a chance to see if it's faster.

Comment: result[0::2] = lst    how does this line merges the two list?Please clarify

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> list('-'.join(ls))
['a', '-', 'b', '-', 'c', '-', 'd', '-', 'e']
>>>
```

Comment: Note that this only works if all items and the seperator are single-character strings!

Comment: This is true, but this was also the exact, explicit use case that was given by OP.

Answer (score 13):

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
result = []
for e in list:
    result.append(e)
    result.append('-')
result.pop()
```

seems to work

Answer (score 7):

This should work with any list elements:

```
>>> sep = '-'
>>> ls = [1, 2, 13, 14]
>>> sum([[i, '-'] for i in ls], [])[:-1]
[1, '-', 2, '-', 13, '-', 14]
```

Comment: Better, and I find the best: ``print sum((['-',i] for i in ls), ls[0:1])``

Comment: Summing lists is O(n²); it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: So where are you using `sep`?

Answer (score 4):

The following will add a "separator" element between each of those in a list:

```
seq = ['a','b','c','d','e']

def tween(seq, sep):
    return reduce(lambda r,v: r+[sep,v], seq[1:], seq[:1])

print tween(seq, '-')
```

output:

```
['a', '-', 'b', '-', 'c', '-', 'd', '-', 'e']
```

FWIW, here's a similar thread titled [*Custom string joining*](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/e3083b83301e0630?hl=en#) in the Usenet `comp.lang.python` group that might interest you.

Answer (score 2):

```
li = ['a','b','c','d','e']
for i in xrange(len(li)-1,0,-1):
    li[i:i] = '-'
```

or

```
from operator import concat
seq = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print reduce(concat,[['-',x] for x in seq[1:]],seq[0:1])
```

or

```
li = ['a','b','c','d','e']
newli = li[0:1]
[ newli.extend(('-',x)) for x in li[1:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little more elegant/pythonic as well as being general.  You may find it less readable if you are not used to a functional style though:

```
li = ['a','b','c','d','e']

from operator import add
reduce(add, [(elt, "-") for elt in li])[:-1]
```

If you like, you could use lambda a, b: a+b instead of operator.add.

Comment: Tower I had the same idea but with **li[0:1]** as start: ``reduce(concat,[['-',x] for x in li[1:]],li[0:1])`` Upvoted

Comment: This is O(n²); an O(n) solution is easily possible.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion/3682033#3682033):

```
>>> input = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> sep = ['-'] * len(input)
>>> list(sum(zip(input, sep), ())[:-1])
['a', '-', 'b', '-', 'c', '-', 'd', '-', 'e']
```

[Another answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion/3678930#3678930) does this using itertools and a slightly modified separator list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> sep = ['-'] * (len(input) - 1)
>>> list(it.next() for it in itertools.cycle((iter(input), iter(sep))))
['a', '-', 'b', '-', 'c', '-', 'd', '-', 'e']
```