# Inserting an item after each item in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, insert

Say I have a list like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
filler = ['cat']
```

How could I get

```
b = [[1 ,2 ,3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

As an output?

Comment: Related, but I guess not _quite_ a duplicate: [Add an item between each item already in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5920643/577088).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
import itertools

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
filler = ['cat']
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, [filler] * len(a))))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

Comment: `itertools.chain` is the canonical way to flatten, rather than creating your own join.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use itertools for stuff like this:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> filler = ['cat']
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(it.izip(a, it.repeat(filler))))
[[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the `itertools`-based solutions posted here, but here's an approach that doesn't require list comprehensions or `itertools`, and I bet it's super fast.

```
new_list = [filler] * (len(a) * 2)
new_list[0::2] = a
```

Comment: This is approximately three times faster than the `itertools` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Not pythonic but seems to work.

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
result = []
for e in list:
    result.append(e)
    result.append(['cat'])
result.pop()
```

Found at this post:
[Add an item between each item already in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920643/add-an-item-between-each-item-already-in-the-list?rq=1)

Comment: I saw that post, but all those examples return error messages for me.

Answer (score 1):

something like this using [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

`cycle()` is used to repeat an item, and used `islice()` cut the number of repeatation to `len(a)`, and then use [`izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) or simple `zip()` over `a` and the iterator returned by `islice()` ,
this will return  list of tuples.

you can then flatten this using [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
In [72]: a
Out[72]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [73]: b
Out[73]: ['cat']

In [74]: cyc=islice(cycle(b),len(a))

In [75]: lis=[]

In [76]: for x in a:
    lis.append(x)
    lis.append([next(cyc)])
   ....:     

In [77]: lis
Out[77]: [[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

or:

```
In [108]: a
Out[108]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [109]: b
Out[109]: ['cat']

In [110]: cyc=islice(cycle(b),len(a))

In [111]: list(chain(*[(x,[y]) for x,y in izip(a,cyc)]))
Out[111]: [[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

Comment: Why not just use flatten for the joining?

Comment: It's incorrect in that (a) it's not especially well written; and (b) it completely fails to capture the benefits of either iterators or explicit iteration by bastardising the two.

Comment: @Marcin added a `chain()` based anwser that used flattening.

Comment: I still don't think is especially useful, because of the way it is written, and the lack of explication, but I have withdrawn my downvote.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary your answer was never incorrect, don't let yourself get sucked into an argument, just ignore the troll among us. +1 to this answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I just saw your answer and a +1 to your answer as well which didn't deserved a -1, I think it's unreasonable to -1 an answer just on the basis of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
filler = ['cat']
out = []

for i in a:
    out.append(i)
    out.append(filler)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [si for i in zip(a, [filler]*len(a)) for si in i]
```

Comment: -1 cryptic list comprehension used for flattening without explication. There's a perfectly good library function to achieve the same effect.

Comment: +1, because I don't think it should _always_ be necessary to import a module for a simple, one-off transformation like this. _But_ -- I would break it into two separate lines. `pairs = zip(a, [filler] * len(a)); chained_pairs = [item for pair in pairs for item in pair]`. It's more self-documenting that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as a one-liner:

```
from operator import add
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
filler = ['cat']

reduce(add, ([x, filler] for x in a))
> [[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

Or even simpler, without using `reduce`:

```
sum(([x, filler] for x in a), [])
> [[1, 2, 3], ['cat'], [4, 5, 6], ['cat']]
```

Both solutions do the same: first, create a generator of `[element, filler]` and then flatten the resulting stream of pairs. For efficiency, the first step is performed using generators to avoid unnecessary intermediate lists.

**UPDATE:**

This post is a textbook example of why a troll must not be fed in an online forum. See the comments to see what I mean. It's better to just ignore the troll.

Answer (score -1):

```
    python 3.2

    a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    b = ['cat']
    _=[a.insert(x,b) for x in range(1,len(a)*2,2)]
```