# Join equivalent for iterables: insert delimiter object between entries

Tags: python

I want to insert a delimiter object between every element of a sequence. One way would be:

```
def join_items(delim, seq):
    result = []
    for x in seq:
        result.append(x)
        result.append(delim)
    if result:
        del result[-1]
    return result
```

But it seems like there should be a better way. Is there?

Comment: Not for arbitrary iterables, no.

Comment: some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920643/add-an-item-between-each-item-already-in-the-list

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. Your link's answer is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655708/python-most-elegant-way-to-intersperse-a-list-with-an-element