# List comprehension with several elements per entry

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This one is clear:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x = [v for v in a]
```

But I am not sure how to do this:

```
sep = 5
# ??? y = [v + sep for v in a]
print y # expected ['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

How can I write a list comprehension with multiple elements per source element?

I am not interested in optimizations of this code: please do not refer to the `[:]` operator or `join` method or something on those lines. My code needs a list comprehension. The only alternative I have at the moment is a 4 lines `for` loop, which is inconvenient:

```
y = []
for v in a:
    y.append(v)
    y.append(sep)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655803/1628832

Answer (score 6):

Using <del>nested</del> list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> [item  for x in a for item in (x, 5)]
['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

Comment: Nice, seems to be fastest by far.

Answer (score 5):

You can build a `list` of `tuples` first, and then flatten the resulting list using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> sep = 5
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((elem, sep) for elem in a))
['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

Comment: As @RohitJain was faster, let me add that a list comprehension will give you at most one element in your result for each element of the list that you traverse.  You want to have two.  I believe this is only possible with something along the lines that Rohit suggests.

Comment: @nickie. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The comment is meant as an explanation why this cannot be done just with one list comprehension traversing `a` (i.e., without the extra flattening).  If you understand it and can write it better, please do.  If you think there's no hope, I'll erase it.

Comment: @nickie. Oh! No leave it. No issues.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the function `sum()` to flatten the list of list as `[[v,sep] for v in a]` will produce `[['a', 5], ['b', 5], ['c', 5]]`

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x = [v for v in a]
sep = 5
y = sum([[v,sep] for v in a],[])
print y
#['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

Comment: For long lists, this is performs very poorly algorithmically.

Comment: +1, Interesting use of sum.  You are not using x at all here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect problem to show how powerful Python's itertool package is

[repeat:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) Creates an endless (or upto a limit) iterable of an object

[izip:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) Transposes the iterables.

[chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) Unwraps an iterable

```
>>> from itertools import izip, chain, repeat
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(a, repeat(5))))
['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

And if you have a knack for micro optimization, you may be interested to know, this is faster than list comprehension

```
>>> stmt1 = """
list(chain.from_iterable((elem, 5) for elem in a))
"""
>>> stmt2 = """
list(chain.from_iterable(izip(a, repeat(5))))
"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt1, setup="from __main__ import chain, a", number=100000)
1.3136643729533688
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt2, setup="from __main__ import chain, izip, repeat, a", number=100000)
0.8959859753707633
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [5 if i % 2 else a[i/2] for i in range(2*len(a))]
```

(Not that you should put code like this into production)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [item for sublist in zip(a, [5]*len(a)) for item in sublist]
['a', 5, 'b', 5, 'c', 5]
```

To break it down:

```
>>> [5]*len(a)
[5, 5, 5]

>>> zip(a, [5]*len(a))
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 5)]
```

The list of tuples is then flattened using the following idiom:

```
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Using timeit, this approach was 15% faster than the fastest itertools method

```
>>> stmt3 = """
[item for sublist in zip(a, [5]*len(a)) for item in sublist]
"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt3, setup="a = ['a', 'b', 'c']", number=100000)
```

Comment: falsetru has a much better and >2x faster solution along these lines below.