# Separate list by item using List comprehension

Tags: python

Given a list, how I generate the list separated by a give value

```
# Problem
items = ["a", "b", "c"]
expected_result = ["a", "separator", "b", "separator", "c"]

# solution should look like

items = [ item, "separator" for item in items]
```

Comment: Please kindly provide with what you have tried

Comment: I tried ```items = [ [item, "separator"] for item in items]```  I ended up with a 2D list

Comment: It might also help if you explain why you want this? If your end goal is to combine the list into a string, you could write `'separator'.join(items)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: most elegant way to intersperse a list with an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655708/python-most-elegant-way-to-intersperse-a-list-with-an-element)

Comment: This seems like an xy problem. What will you do with the resulting list? Why do you want it?

Comment: I think it is impossible with list comprehensions

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040525/insert-element-in-python-list-after-every-nth-element)

Comment: I did it using list comprehension, can this be re-opened? or should I link to my solution somehow?

Comment: This actually can be done with list comprehension. See below:

    result = [item for raw_item in items for item in [raw_item, 'separator']]

Comment: @DavidKaftan your solution will end up having a trailing 'separator'. My solution, although not very elegant, works fine with both odd and even sized lists. `result = [ items[int(i/2)] if i%2==0 else "separator" for i in range((2*len(items))-1) ]`

Comment: yeah, I suppose you could also just do `[item for raw_item in items for item in [raw_item, 'separator']][:-1]`

Comment: yup, that's also a possibility, i guess it just depends on what the OP is trying to do

Answer (score 2):

```
items = ["a", "b", "c"]
separated_list = []
for element in items:
    separated_list += [element]
    separated_list += ["separator"]
separated_list = separated_list[:-1]
```