# Override or augment setuptools build_ext error messages

Tags: python, error-handling, setuptools, python-packaging, code-documentation

I'm trying to build on a fresh Linux installation a CFFI-based package I'm maintaining.

However, out of the box, the errors it gives about the dependencies pip couldn't fetch (attached at the end of this post) are useless and inscrutable.

I want to **catch, override, or somehow augment** these error messages so I can give the naive user trying to execute `python -m build` or `pip install .` on a new platform some actually meaningful, **actionable** error messages suggesting what packages to install (including, for example, the link to Windows' [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)).

My project is pyproject.toml-based, with the default backend / no backend specified. It seems to be using `build_ext` due to its cffi build-time dependency.

How can this be done?

---

#### Appendix: Error messages

The solution to this one was `dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools'`/`apt install build-essential`:

```
…
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece348864.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece460896.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece6688128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece6960119.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece8192128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
running build_ext
…
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
$
```

The solution to this one was `dnf install python3-devel`/`apt install python3-dev`:

```
…
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece348864.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece460896.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece6688128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece6960119.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
copying pqc/kem/mceliece8192128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc/kem
running build_ext
…
build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pqc._lib.mceliece348864f_clean.c:50:14: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
   50 | #    include <pyconfig.h>
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
$
```

---

#### Appendix 2: MRE

As requested by a guy in the comments, here is a "minimal reproducible example" of a CFFI-based setuptools package which will demonstrate these errors, in case you are unfamiliar with them yet hope to answer this question anyway — this will allow you to reproduce the error on any **fresh installation** of Windows 10 or Ubuntu LTS (I don't know enough about Python use on Macs to say how the cookie would crumble there, though):

```py
from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
import os
from pathlib import Path
import platform
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import tempfile
from textwrap import dedent
import venv

BUILD_CMD = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-v', '.']


def main():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        td = os.path.realpath(td)
        venv.create(td, with_pip=True)
        root = Path(td) / 'stackoverflow-77686182'
        root.mkdir()

        # 1. create setup.py
        (root / 'setup.py').write_text(dedent('''\
        # https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/cffi/-/issues/441
        # https://github.com/python-cffi/cffi/issues/55
        from setuptools import setup
        
        setup(
            cffi_modules = [
                'cffi_module.py:ffi'
            ]
        )
        '''))

        # 2. create CFFI module
        (root / 'cffi_module.py').write_text(dedent('''\
        from cffi import FFI
        from pathlib import Path
        root = Path(__file__).parent
        
        ffibuilder = FFI()
        ffibuilder.cdef('unsigned short spam();')
        ffibuilder.set_source(
            'stackoverflow_77686182._libspam',
            '#include "libspam.h"',
            sources=[(root / 'libspam.c').as_posix()],
            include_dirs=[root.as_posix()]
        )
        ffi = ffibuilder
        '''))

        # 3. create C source
        (root / 'libspam.c').write_text(dedent('''\
        unsigned short spam() {
            return 69;
        }
        '''))

        # 4. Create C headers
        (root / 'libspam.h').write_text(dedent('''\
        unsigned short spam();
        '''))

        # 5. Create Python package code
        (root / 'src' / 'stackoverflow_77686182').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        (root / 'src' / 'stackoverflow_77686182' / '__init__.py').write_text(dedent('''\
        from . import _libspam
        '''))
        (root / 'src' / 'stackoverflow_77686182' / '__main__.py').write_text(dedent('''\
        from stackoverflow_77686182._libspam import ffi, lib
        if lib.spam() == 69:
            print('OK')
        else:
            raise AssertionError('FAIL')
        '''))

        # 6. Create Python packaging metadata
        (root / 'pyproject.toml').write_text(dedent('''\
        [project]
        name = 'stackoverflow_77686182'
        version = '0'
        dependencies = [
            'cffi >= 1.0.0;platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"',
        ]
        
        [build-system]
        requires = [
            'cffi >= 1.14',
            'setuptools >= 49.5.0'
        ]
        '''))

        (root / 'requirements-dev.txt').write_text(dedent('''\
        pip >= 21.1.3
        setuptools >= 49.5.0
        '''))

        # 7. Build and install
        _check_call_in_venv(td, ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', root / 'requirements-dev.txt'])
        _check_call_in_venv(td, BUILD_CMD, cwd=root)

        # 8. Run 
        _check_call_in_venv(td, ['python', '-m', 'stackoverflow_77686182'])
        raise NotImplementedError('This script should be run on a machine that LACKS the necessary items for a CFFI project build, but the build seems to have succeeded.')


def _check_call_in_venv(env_dir, cmd, *a, **k):
    script = []
    is_win = (platform.system() == 'Windows')
    script.append(['.', Path(env_dir) / 'bin' / 'activate'] if not is_win else [Path(env_dir) / 'Scripts' / 'activate.bat'])
    script.append(cmd)
    _cmd = ['sh', '-c', ';\n'.join(shlex.join(cmd) for cmd in ['set -e'] + script)] if not is_win else f'cmd /C "{" ".join(_intersperse("&&", (" ".join(map(str, cmd)) for cmd in script)))}"'
    return subprocess.check_call(_cmd, *a, **k)


def _intersperse(delim, seq):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/5656097/1874170
    return islice(chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat(delim), seq)), 1, None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I guess you are on the right track.Try to override/extend setuptools' `build_ext` command.

Comment: Tracing the setuptools spaghetti, it looks like [`setuptools._distutils.unixccompiler.UnixCCompiler:_compile()`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v69.1.1/setuptools/_distutils/unixccompiler.py#L187) \([et cetera](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v69.1.1/setuptools/_distutils/msvccompiler.py#L428)\) is the culprit; it's apparently *ultimately* called by [`setuptools.setup` itself](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v69.1.1/setuptools/_distutils/core.py#L185)... or at least it *would* be, if I weren't using pyproject.toml  more investigation is needed

Comment: Well, pypa/build [ultimately seems to call](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/1.0.3/src/build/__init__.py#L298) your ["backend"](https://github.com/pypa/pyproject-hooks/blob/v1.0.0/src/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py#L66)'s `build_wheel`, which does [appear to be](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/1.0.3/src/build/__init__.py#L51) [setuptools'](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v69.1.1/setuptools/build_meta.py#L406) in my case.

Comment: So now I just need to figure out where and how to inject a `try` statement. Looks like maybe I'll need to migrate from setuptools-as-default-backend to an *explicitly declared* pseudo-subclass of `build_meta`?

Comment: The default errors/exceptions displayed are very common and easy to look up online. So all in all, it might be the right decision to leave things as is and people will be able to figure it out. -- You can also add some hints in the documentation of your project. -- Maybe you could ask *setuptools* directly: ***1.*** where to place the try/catch ***2.*** if there is a way to add better error messages in *setuptools* directly (maybe you can hoffer to help with writing this code yourself).

Comment: @sinoroc The opinion you're expressing there is the negation of the very premise of my question. I can respect that *you* believe these errors are "easy" to resolve, but that's **irrelevant** because I explicitly stated in my question that I'm trying to augment these errors because they suck; they were never made to be user-facing [in the first place](https://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A222%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2Cnull%2C529%2Cnull%5D); I found them confusing, aggravating, and difficult to resolve, and want to save the next guy some pain.

Comment: @sinoroc As for your suggestions, I am currently pursuing both of those. \[[1](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4216#:~:text=This%20is%20severely%20suboptimal,%2E), [2](https://github.com/JamesTheAwesomeDude/pypqc/issues/13)\]

Comment: If you rewrite your question (or write a new one), with the actual code you have written to "override or augment" the setuptools command, the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and so on, then we can probably do something on StackOverflow. In other words, on StackOverflow, what is expected from your question is a full, standalone [mre].