str.join() equivalent for generic iterables
How do I implement a join() function that behaves like this?
>>> separator = [')', '-a', '(']
>>> args = [['-name', '*.py'], ['-type', 'f'], ['-mtime', '0']]
>>> list(join(separator, args))
["-name", "*.py", ")", "-a", "(", "-type", "f", ")", "-a", "(", "-mtime", "0"]


the purpose of join is to join list elements into a string. this is not a desirable behavior

@folengateis Just because you don't desire this functionality doesn't mean nobody does.

@nocomment as a general rule, of course. but in this particular case, the name is deceptive so it must be avoided

@folengateis Could suggest a better name? I also considered calling it chain_with_separator

@folengateis Nonsense, the name is perfectly alright and appropriate.

This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655708/python-most-elegant-way-to-intersperse-a-list-with-an-element

@mkrieger1 Half-answer. Since it's only for single elements, not for sequences.

def join(sep, iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)

    try:
        first = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield from first

    for i in iterator:
        yield from sep
        yield from i


And you might want to store the sep elements in a list, so you can indeed use them repeatedly even if sep is an iterator.

This code will not produce a list of strings (which you state is required)

@SIGHUP Where did they state that?

@nocomment The last line of the question shows a list of strings

@SIGHUP That's apparently just because all input elements are strings.

@SIGHUP No need to be disrespectful. Note that the call to join() in the example is wrapped around list(), so the generator will be iterated and yield a list.
